# "It makes sense for the promisor to request, as the price of his promise, that the other party should benefit some third party"?

Tags: contract-law, england-and-wales

[*O'Sullivan & Hilliard's The Law of Contract*](https://www.amazon.co.uk/OSullivan-Hilliards-Law-Contract-Janet/dp/0198807821/ref=dp_ob_title_bk) (2018 8 ed). p. 93.

> [image]

Can 'the other party' (underlined in red) be interchanged with 'promisee' here?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes.  How else can you read it?

Comment: I don't know. I'm just bemused that the author didn't simply write "promisee".

Comment: The author's English teacher probably taught them that you should avoid repeating the same word.  Instead you should employ "elegant variation", and find a different phrasing every time.  This is *very bad advice* for technical writing.

Comment: Thanks again. I had reckoned that the author, as an intelligent knowledgeable law professor, would know better than to employ "elegant variation".